# How to create an RVM environment on a server through net-ssh?

Tags: rvm, capistrano, net-ssh, rvm-capistrano

I have a script which is installing Ruby/RVM (and more) on my server to get an environment ready to deploy a Rails project. This script is in ruby and use the net-ssh lib to do the job.

After having installed RVM, Ruby, I would like to create the project Gemset:

```
connection do |conn|
  logger("Create RVM environment #{ruby_version}@#{project_name}")
  conn.exec!("#{rvmsudo_path} #{rvm_path} gemset create #{project_name}")   
end
```

I get my gemset created under, all good:

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project_name

Here is my Capistrano setting for rvm/ruby:

```
set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")
```

When I'm trying to deploy using capistrano, I get:

> /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project_name: Permission denied

The environment file 'ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project_name' is actually missing in that folder. I need to log into the server and navigate to my project so the .rvmrc file to trigger the creation of the environment (rvm --create my_project_name). I would like to avoid this last step. Do you know how to trigger the creation of this environment? (I though it would create it when I have created the Gemset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the RVM environment need to be loaded to be able to script it remotely.
https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting/

You can run the following command with net-ssh to do so:

```
conn.exec!("source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm; rvm --create ruby-1.9.3-p286@my_project_name")
```

It will create your environment and associated gemset.

Comment: replacing `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` with `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` if you installed RVM as a user (which is recommended).

Answer (score 0):

RVM has support for installing itself via capistrano, to install rubies and to create gemsets, you should make use of it:

- https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/#install_rvm
- https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/#install_ruby

Comment: yes I know, but I don't find this very useful as I need RVM to be installed to install Passenger and other things before I do anything with my project.

Comment: why can you not install passenger via capistrano?